# EF Core 3.1: Sequence contains no elements with FromSqlRaw query a stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I try to query a stored procedure with Entity Framework Core 3.1. I made a really simple test project.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcTest]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select tbl_Postalcode.PST_T_PostalCode AS Postalcode
    from tbl_Postalcode
END
```

**Entity:**

```
public class Test
{
    string Postalcode { get; set; }
}
```

**I use this extensions Methods, found on Stackoverflow, that encapsulate the whole thing a bit. But nothing special.:**

```cs
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static IList<T> SqlQuery<T>(this DbContext context, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
    {
        using (var dbcontext = new ContextForQueryType<T>(context.Database.GetDbConnection()))
        {
            return dbcontext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<IList<T>> SqlQueryAsync<T>(this DbContext context, string sql, params object[] parameters) where T : class
    {
        using (var dbcontext = new ContextForQueryType<T>(context.Database.GetDbConnection()))
        {
            return await dbcontext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    private class ContextForQueryType<T> : DbContext where T : class
    {
        private readonly System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection;

        public ContextForQueryType(System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection)
        {
            this.connection = connection;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasNoKey();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Then i execute the query like this:**

```
var result = await _myContext.SqlQueryAsync<Test>("Exec prcTest");
```

**And i get this error:**

```
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Sequence contains no elements)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()


System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoCommon<TClass, TDeclaredProperty, TRuntimeProperty, TConverter>.GetValueAsObject(object obj)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleEnumerable(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int originalWriterDepth, int flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, ref WriteStack state)
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Can anyone give me an idea what the specific problem is?

Comment: I would say the error is not related to the query itself but the API result serialization - based on the error. Can you please add full action code?

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks for the hint regarding serialization. I posted the solution.

Comment: Was glad to help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution. The error message is not helpful and very confusing.

**The solution:**

Make the property public. It is so obvious but the error message confused me.

```
public class Test
{
    public string Postalcode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Indeed error is absolutely non descriptive for this issue

Comment: Thank you! Just in case someone else runs into this, in my case the properties where public however they did not have { get; set; } and I still got this very non-descriptive error.